# Strtok isn't returning as expected, am I using it wrong?

Tags: c, split, c-strings, strtok, function-definition

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// fiter string to the first |
char* filterstringfirst(char* command, int i){
    char *tok = command;
    int x = 0;
    while ((tok = strtok(tok, "|")) != NULL && x <= i)
    {
        if( x == i){
            return tok;
        }
        x++;
        printf(" ===  Parsed: --%s-- ===\n", tok);
        tok = NULL;
    }
    return tok;
        
}


int main () {
    char command[]  = "ls -a | sort -h | grep h | wc -l";
    
    char command2[]  = "ls -a | sort -h | grep h | wc -l";
    char* temp = command;

    char* x =  filterstringfirst(temp, 0);
    printf("%s\n",x);
    char* temp2 = command;

    char* x2 =  filterstringfirst(temp2, 1);
    printf("%s\n",x2);
    
    
   
    temp = command;
    

   return 0;
}
```

I have this function I made which is supposed to just return part of a string. The original string should be similar to "ls -l | grep temp | sort".

The idea was that it would be called with the string and a number, and return that segment. Eg. 0 -> "ls -l"

Now this works the first time I call it, but calling it again seems to break and end in a segfault.

```
char command[]  = "ls -a | sort -h | grep h | wc -l";
char* temp = command;

char* x =  filterstringfirst(temp, 0);
printf("%s\n",x);
char* temp2 = command;

char* x2 =  filterstringfirst(temp2, 1);
printf("%s\n",x2);`
```

This was my testing code

And the output:

```
ls -a  
===  Parsed: --ls -a -- === 
[1]    1126 segmentation fault  ./templ
 ➜  Current gcc -o templ templ.c
 ➜  Current ./templ ls -a  
===  Parsed: --ls -a -- === [1]   
 1136 segmentation fault  ./templ
```

Edit: Updated to have main too (based on comments)

Comment: @WeatherVane I was going to say the same thing, but then I saw `tok = NULL;` at the bottom of the loop.

Comment: Your code would be easier to read for yourself and other people if you used [indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style). Edit: Meanwhile, someone else has added the indentation for you.

Comment: @Barmar mybad: not sharp enough to see past the (lack of) formatting.

Comment: The second call to `filterstringfirst` won't work, because `strtok()` modifies the string.

Comment: Why do you need the `temp` and `temp2` variables? You can just use `filterstringfirst(command, ...)`

Comment: The check of `tok` here is also unnecessary: `if( x == i && tok != NULL)` because you won't be in the loop if `tok == NULL`.

Comment: Edited to include full code, sorry guys. New here!

Comment: I noticed it isn't `const char[]`. How attached are you to those strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtok` is *destructive* - it modifies the buffer passed in by replacing delimiters will null bytes.

After

```
char* x =  filterstringfirst(temp, 0);
```

`command` will effectively be `"ls -a "`.

If you want to use `strtok` here, you will either need to:

- mimic `strtok` in your wrapping function, by passing `NULL` and the position to start from in subsequent calls, or
- duplicate the string before using it, and return a copy of the token.

An example of the second, with no error handling:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *get_token_at(char *command, size_t n) {
    size_t position = 0;
    char *copy = strdup(command);
    char *token = strtok(copy, "|");
    char *output = NULL;

    while (token && position < n) {
        token = strtok(NULL, "|");
        position++;
    }

    if (token && position == n)
        output = strdup(token);

    free(copy);

    return output;
}

int main(void) {
    char command[]  = "ls -a | sort -h | grep h | wc -l";

    char *x = get_token_at(command, 0);
    puts(x);
    free(x);

    x = get_token_at(command, 1);
    puts(x);
    free(x);
}
```

`stdout`:

```
ls -a 
 sort -h
```

*(Note the whitespace in these tokens.)*

Answer (score 1):

The function `strtok` changes the passed string by inserting zero characters '\0' in the positions of delimiters.

So after the first call of the function `filterstringfirst`

```
char* x =  filterstringfirst(temp, 0);
```

the character array `command` looks like

```
"ls -a \0 sort -h | grep h | wc -l";
       ^^^
```

That is in fact you have the following string `"ls -a "` stored in the array `command`.

So calling the function the second time with the second argument greater than 0 you will get as a result a null pointer.

If you want to extract substrings specifying an index then you should use functions `strspn` and `strcspn` and return from the function a dynamically allocated array containing the target substring.

Here is a demonstration program that shows how the function can be defined using the standard string functions `strspn` and `strcspn` and **without creating dynamically a copy of the source string (that is inefficient and unsafe) each time when the function is called.**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * filterstringfirst( const char *command, const char *delimiters, size_t i ) 
{
    char *substring = NULL;

    const char *p = command;
    size_t n = 0;

    do
    {
        p += n;
        p += strspn( p, delimiters );
        n = strcspn( p, delimiters );
    } while (*p && i--);

    if ( *p && ( substring = malloc( n + 1 ) ) != NULL )
    {
        memcpy( substring, p, n );
        substring[n] = '\0';
    }

    return substring;
}

int main( void )
{
    char command[] = "ls -a | sort -h | grep h | wc -l";
    const char *delimiters = "|";

    char *substring = NULL;

    for (size_t i = 0;
        ( substring = filterstringfirst( command, delimiters, i ) ) != NULL;
        i++)
    {
        printf( "%zu: \"%s\"\n", i, substring );
        free( substring );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
0: "ls -a "
1: " sort -h "
2: " grep h "
3: " wc -l"
```

You can use this function with any delimiters used to separate a string.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! I'm assuming the best way to go about this would be a loop and pointers then? 

Is there a better way I'm missing?

Comment: @DynamicApproach You could call the function without the second parameter sequentially passing NULL to it after the first call.

Comment: removing the second param, so no int?


So calling it once gets the "ls -a"

Then calling it again gets the "sort -h"?


Am I correct in that thinking?


Eg.
`char* filterstringfirst(char* command){
    char *tok = command;
    int x = 0;
    while ((tok = strtok(tok, "|")) != NULL )
    {
        x++;
        printf(" ===  Parsed: --%s-- ===\n", tok);
        tok = NULL;
    }
    return tok;
}`

Comment: @DynamicApproach The variable x is redundant. You should track the number of a substring in the caller of the function.